# Let $\space \chi \mod k \space$ be the Dirichlet Character. Is $\space |\chi(n)|=1 \space$ for all $\space n\in (\mathbb{Z} / k\mathbb{Z})^\times $?

Tags: absolute-value, characters, dirichlet-series

Sorry for the lengthy question. But is this statement true? Because in all papers on the Dirichlet character I read, they assume this to be true but don't really provide an explanation.

For example, I've seen:

> $|{\chi(n) \over n^s}|={1\over |n^s|} \space$ for all $\space s\in\mathbb{C} \space$ with real part greater than $\space 1 \space$.

Sorry if this is obvious, but I can't seem to get my head around it.

Comment: Not only for the Dirichlet character, but for every character $\chi$ you have $|\chi(x)|=1$ because $\chi(x)$ is a root of unity.

Comment: A Dirichlet character is a homomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}_k)^* \to \mathbb{C}^*$. Since the former has finite order, so does its image in the latter.

Comment: A Dirichlet character is a special case of a group homomorphism $\chi:G\to\mathbb C^*$. For every group $G$ in which each element $g$ has finite order, $\chi(g)^k=\chi(g^k)=\chi(id)=1$ where $k$ is the order of $g$. So $\chi(g)$ is a root of unity. (Just to elaborate on the comment above.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, a character is a group homomorphism $\chi:G\to\mathbb C^\times$ and so induces a group homomorphism $\phi:G\to\mathbb R_+^\times$ given by $\phi(g)=|\chi(g)|$, since $z \mapsto |z|$ is a group homomorphism $\mathbb C^\times\to\mathbb R_+^\times$.

Any group homomorphism takes torsion elements to torsion elements.

If $G$ is finite, then all elements in $G$ are torsion elements.
Therefore, $\phi$ takes all elements of $G$ to $1$, the only torsion element of $\mathbb R_+^\times$, that is, $|\chi(g)|=1$ for all $g \in G$.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "induces a homomorphism"?. What does it mean for homomorphism to induce a homomorphism?

Comment: Sorry for the vague question.

Comment: Never mind, I've just gotten it. Thank you very much :)